# objects with key: value in Java

Tags: java

I have just started to learn Java. Read a small book but I didnt catch information about key: value objects.

for example in javascript:

```
let car = {
           type:"Fiat", 
           model:"500", 
           color:"white"
           };
```

but in java there is only classes, which create an object:

```
public class CarObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car car = new Car("Fiat", "500", "White");
    }
}
class Car{
    String type;
    String model;
    String color;
    public Car(String type, String model, String color){
        this.color = color;
        this.model = model;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

So, my question is if in Java language there is no such thing like key: value. Or there is no sense to use it, because of used classes?

Comment: You can use a [HashMap](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp) or any type of map (depending on your use case).

Comment: Refer to [The Map Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Answer (score 1):

Key:Value pairs concept exists in java and for that you can always utilize [Map Interfaces](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/map).
The Map interface in Java is part of the Collections framework and provides the functionality of map data structure; which means mapping a key to a value.

However, a class is a blueprint for creating new objects/entities; such entity or object when created has its own state and behavior.

Map data structure and Class/Object have no contradiction. A Map could be used to define an objects state or be produced as the result of an objects behavior.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [Map interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) and its implementations.

The most used one is HashMap. Which you declare like:

```
Map<typeOfKey,typeOfValue> aMap = new HashMap<typeOfKey,typeOfValue>()
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, my question is if in Java language there is no such thing like key: value.[1] Or there is no sense to use it, because of used classes? [2]

[1] There is what ever wanted to be in each programming language. Maybe, some programming languages have specific features (eg: OOP, functional Interface, various data types). Do your own if what is provided is not enough.

[2] `Key-Values` reflect better a paradigm of programing, saying other a way of convenient storage which latter will ease the programming work.

One of java features is `Map- type` a `List of elements stored as <key,value>`, but this is not necessary the only way (better an alternative).

With a small example, `Cat(identifier, name)` and if wanted to store use a List of type Cat `List<Cat>`. `Name` is not required to be a property (cat name), can be what ever you wanted (an instance). `Cat(id, (name, hair color, tail length))` -> instance of dog friend.